# Блокировка дескриптора окна Windows

Tags: windows

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Не могу победить заразу. 
Случайно установил Shel оболочку runpad на win7. Как потом оказалось последняя версия не имеет режима админа и мне пришлось удалять его в ручную. Все удалил и разблокировал все,почти все, функции win7.
Одно победить не могу.
Теперь не работают диалоговые окна @сохранить как@. Я так полагаю что где то(реестр/политики и т.д) стоит блокировка по дескриптору окна. В какую сторону копать? где/чем может выполняться такая блокировка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что библиотека ComDlg32.dll  была через реестр изменена на другую. после перерегистрации все наладилось

Answer (score 1):

Классический Open диалог - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32`

Новый Open диалог - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CIDOpen`

Save диалог - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CIDSave`

Откройте `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`

Там должны присутствовать подразделы ComDlg32, CIDOpen, CIDSave.
Если они там отсутствуют, вам необходимо восстановить их.

Comment: А еще можно переустановить систему)

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Все указанные ветки в реестре есть.